# Is there any way to modify this query and remove subquery in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say

```
SELECT T1.A
      ,T1.B
      ,T2.X
      ,T2.Y
      ,(SELECT T1.C WHERE T1.K=T2.K) --Specific Condition only for this column
  FROM TABLE1 AS T1
  JOIN TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.G = T2.G
```

My question is since `Table1` and `Table2` are joined, how do I remove the 5th line in the query

```
(SELECT T1.C WHERE T1.K = T2.K)
```

since same tables (`TABLE1` and `TABLE2`) are being joined. Is there any way to eliminate this line and condition so that it yields same number of rows?

Comment: You query has syntax error: `SELECT T1.C` from what table(s)? It would help if you included few sample rows from your tables and what the end result should look like.

Answer (score 3):

Does this give you the same result? I'm surprised it works as it - if the relationship on `T1.K=T2.K` is not 1-1 then you would get an error.

```
SELECT T1.A
      ,T1.B
      ,T2.X
      ,T2.Y
      ,CASE WHEN T1.K=T2.K THEN T1.C ELSE NULL END 
  FROM TABLE1 AS T1
  JOIN TABLE2 AS T2
    ON T1.G = T2.G
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you posted looks very much like a simplified sample, so it's not a query that you actually use and have verified to be working correctly.

Right?

The reason I ask is that, as pointed out in a comment, your query most likely  contains an error and would not qive you what I think you want. It should probably be this (?):

```
SELECT T1.A
      ,T1.B
      ,T2.X
      ,T2.Y
      ,(SELECT T3.C FROM TABLE1 AS T3 WHERE T3.K=T2.K) --Specific Condition only for this column
FROM TABLE1 AS T1
    JOIN TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.G = T2.G
```

Even so, the query would cause an error when you run it if there are more than one row in TABLE1 with a K value that is also found in TABLE2. The sub query

```
      ,(SELECT T3.C FROM TABLE1 AS T3 WHERE T3.K=T2.K) --Specific Condition
```

would then find two (or more) C values in TABLE1 and more than on value from the sub query cannot go into one row in the outer query. **IF** the data is such that there is only ever one row (at most) in TABLE1 found, then it would work. And in that case this query below should give you the same result:

```
SELECT T1.A
      ,T1.B
      ,T2.X
      ,T2.Y
      ,T3.C
FROM TABLE1 AS T1
    JOIN TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.G = T2.G
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 AS T3 ON T2.K = T3.K
```